# What is the limit on how many files you change owner for in Google Drive/day?

Tags: google-drive

I have a folder with thousands of files in Google Drive. Now I want to move this folder to another user's Google Drive. First I changed the owner of the root folder but that didn't apply to the files in that folder (very confusing). Now I select a bunch of files, click the share-button and then "Transfer ownership" and finally opens the receiving account where I accept the transfer of ownership.

I have been doing this for a week because after a while I get an error message that I have exceeded my sharing quota.

What is weird is that the number of files I can transfer per day varies a lot:

- nov 12 999
- nov 13 800
- nov 14 748
- nov 15 387
- nov 16 481

What is going on here? What is the limit for how many files you share/transfer ownership of per day? Is there a workaround (e.g., something in the "app store) that allows me to transfer all files in one go?

Answer (score 0):

Other options for changing ownership of Google Drive files:

The method of cross-domain transfer with preserving file IDs using Google Shared Drives is well described [here](https://www.tabgeeks.com/tabgeeks-blog/how-to-transfer-ownership-between-domains-in-google-drive).

Summary:

1. Setup Google Shared Drive.
2. Neutralize files' ownership in the Shared Drive.
3. Assign new ownership.

If you do not have access to Google Workspace (former G Suite), you can take advantage of ready-made solutions available in the [Google Workspace Marketplace](https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/search/Transfer%20files) and also available here as a [web application](https://movefiles.app/).

Answer (score 0):

Google has not disclosed how the limit for ownership transfer is set. In the past, several opportunities on online forums and meetings with end-users that I was invited Googlers from the Google Drive team and others teams mentioned that some limits are not disclosed to avoid abuse.

Perhaps the limits published in Google Workspace Admin might help you

https://support.google.com/a/answer/172541?hl=en

> #### Drive upload limits
>
> Individual users can only upload 750 GB each day between My Drive and all shared drives. Users who reach the 750-GB limit or upload a file larger than 750 GB cannot upload additional files that day. Uploads that are in progress will complete. The maximum individual file size that you can upload or synchronize is 5 TB.

Considering the above, instead of looking at the number of files that were transferred each day, you should look at the storage space used by those files.

Comment: Thank you. The files are generally quite small 136 MB for 14 000 files, so far from the size limit described in your quote.